# Playframework/RequireJs javascript files not being optimized

Tags: angularjs, optimization, playframework, requirejs

I'm new to play framework and I'm trying to get it to work with RequireJs.  When I run my app in dev mode everything runs fine, but when I set `application.mode=prod` and start the server with `play start` I'm running into problems.

The browser receives an HTTP404 when attempting to load /assets/javascripts-min/home/main.js.

Here's my Build.scala file

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.google.javascript.jscomp._
import java.io.File

object MyBuild extends Build {

  val appDependencies = Seq (
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    cache
  )

  val appVersion = "0.0.1"

  val appName = "TodoList"

  // set clojure compiler options so it won't choke on modern js frameworks
  val root = new java.io.File(".")
  val defaultOptions = new CompilerOptions()
  defaultOptions.closurePass = true
  defaultOptions.setProcessCommonJSModules(true)
  defaultOptions.setCommonJSModulePathPrefix(root.getCanonicalPath + "/app/assets/javascripts/")
  defaultOptions.setLanguageIn(CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5)

  CompilationLevel.WHITESPACE_ONLY.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(defaultOptions)

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        (Seq(requireJs += "home/main.js", requireJsShim := "home/main.js") ++ closureCompilerSettings(defaultOptions)): _*
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you see "RequireJS optimization has begun..." in the logs ? You should also check if you have any exception during the server start. I've already encountered a FileNotFoundException during optimization and the optimized file wasn't generated (but the play server was started anyway)

Comment: No I don't see that, I also done see any exceptions during server start.  They would be in the file logs\application.log, right?

Comment: Yes, by default logs are appended to `logs/application.log`. If you don't see "RequireJS optimization has begun...", your build configuration is probably incorrect. With settings `requireJs += "main.js"` and `requireJsShim += "main.js"` and the `@helper.requireJs` in the template, I can see the message in the log and everything works fine. (see : https://gist.github.com/mguillermin/9324154)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a conflicting `build.sbt` (in the `root` directory) and `Build.scala` (in the `project` directory) files.  Once I removed the sbt file, the requireJs optimization began working as expected